# Portal 2 freezes on my Fedora, sound loops forever. What could I try?

Tags: linux, audio, fedora, freeze, gaming

It looks like I'm getting the same problem [a lot of people had](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1847560), but reading through 76 pages of Steam discussion seems overwhelming. Long story short, after a very short attempt to play Portal 2, it always freezes with sound looping and no way to interact with the game at all. I'm using Fedora 24, SELinux in permissive mode, integrated graphics on my i7. Here are full system specs:

```
$ inxi -Fx
System:    Host: d-laptop Kernel: 4.6.7-300.fc24.x86_64 x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 6.1.1)
           Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 (Gtk 2.24.29) Distro: Fedora release 24 (Twenty Four)
Machine:   System: LENOVO (portable) product: 20F5003KPB v: ThinkPad X260
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 20F5003KPB v: SDK0J40705 WIN Bios: LENOVO v: R02ET43W (1.16 ) date: 01/05/2016
Battery    BAT0: charge: 22.1 Wh 99.9% condition: 22.1/23.5 Wh (94%) model: LGC 45N1113 status: Full
           BAT1: charge: 9.1 Wh 39.0% condition: 23.3/23.5 Wh (99%) model: LGC 45N1127 status: Charging
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-6600U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 11233
           clock speeds: max: 3400 MHz 1: 481 MHz 2: 516 MHz 3: 499 MHz 4: 519 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel HD Graphics 520 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: Fedora X.org 118.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.1 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.6.7-300.fc24.x86_64
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection I219-LM driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k bus-ID: 00:1f.6
           IF: enp0s31f6 state: down mac: 50:7b:9d:b5:fb:bc
           Card-2: Intel Wireless 8260 driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 04:00.0
           IF: wlp4s0 state: up mac: a4:34:d9:c5:6e:4e
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 480.1GB (87.0% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: KINGSTON_SHSS37A size: 480.1GB temp: 41C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 50G used: 40G (86%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-2
           ID-2: /boot size: 477M used: 152M (34%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
           ID-3: /home size: 237G used: 204G (91%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-3
           ID-4: swap-1 size: 8.20GB used: 0.71GB (9%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-1
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 48.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 4477
Info:      Processes: 303 Uptime: 2 days Memory: 4291.6/7408.9MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 6.1.1
           Client: Shell (zsh 5.2) inxi: 2.3.0
```

What should I try?

Answer (score 0):

Try launching the game with the -safe option. Set your video settings and remove the -safe option on the next launch. Worked for me. Source: https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/2/624076027880761048/

Comment: Please cite and quote the relevant information from your link.